# how modify the already installed content-assist?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

First of, how can I see what plugin manages the CTRL + SPACE content-assist? And how can I modify it in other to add my own stuff. Any help/idea is gladly welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for "Templates". Assuming you're using Java, this is in the Windows -> Preferences menu, then Java->Editor->Templates. For example, the screenshot below shows the CTRL-SPACE content assist when you type "sysout".

[image: The "sysout" template for Java in Eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

If i would have this task, I would go to preferences. Look for content assist settings. Write down some specific text you see in dialog box. Then go to plugins folder, and start to search inside archives. When match is present, open the plugin.xml of that plugin, and you will see the extension points of the plugin. Based on its name, I am pretty sure you will find the appropiate one. Then you can either google it, or look for plugins extending the extension point. Using JDGui or fetching source code of the extension example plugin will help you in disassembling. Eclipse usually not well documented as for extension points, so i do it this way.